# WordPress theme developing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to add submenu to Appearance menu at WordPress like Background, Header, etc. Please, see the screenshot - http://i28.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0322/17/2ea91d7afac4e8a6755cebfef434aa17.png
Anybody know how to do it according to WordPress theme developing standarts?

Comment: Chip Bennett has done a scholar write-up explaining the WordPress settings API. You should give it a read. You can also look at the twenty-ten and twenty-eleven themes for examples (they're pretty well documented). LINK TO Chip's Settings API tutorial: [link](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme functions.php you can add sub menu's by using `add_submenu_page`

```
add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', //this is the appearance menu
                   $page_title, 
                   $menu_title, 
                   $capability, 
                   $menu_slug, 
                   $function 
               );
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

Answer (score 0):

You could create an [admin panel plugin](http://www.devlounge.net/code/constructing-an-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel).

Or

If you want to add a section to the admin panel directly from your theme, then i think [this link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/) provides details that will help guide you (although I'm not sure it covers how to get it into the Appearance menu).

Comment: Yes, I know about plugins but in case If I want to creating themes all inclusive? Or creating plugins is the best in my case?